# Is the reputation graph misrepresenting the numbers?

Tags: support, reputation, graphs

My reputation graph shows a linear progress from August 5 to yesterday, but the truth is the numbers don't quite match up.

[reputation graph http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/8265/graphs.png](http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/8265/graphs.png)

According to the graph, on August 17, my rep was about 50. Through interpolation of the linearly plotted growth on the graph, it claims to represent a rep of 80 on August 27.

However, on August 27 my rep was actually 11.

As the days pass on, will it eventually change to better represent my rep history?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a good look at the little circles, there is no data-point for aug-17. So the graph is correct, just not going to the trouble of adding values for days when there is no change.

And if you hang on for a few months, it will all compress to the left and you will hardly be able to tell.

A workaround: post answers or questions more frequently.

Comment: ok, now I get it: on Aug 28 there ideally is a vertical line, from 11 to 88 or the like...

Comment: giorgian, yes, that would be another design. A little more complex and not really required or desired for the vast majority of rep graphs.